How to handle specific required fields in a model depending on the value of another field in a database?
I am trying to build an Airbnb clone. Depending on whether your listing is an entire place, private room or shared room, it gives you different options to fill out about the bathrooms and locks depending on you answer. And this prompts the question.
How should I handle these situations in which a registry requires certain fields to be filled out depending on the category that it will end up falling in?
And how do I allow the creation of new categories with their own requirements without having to add another data model?
I thought about creating another model to store the names of the fields and their values. But I feel there must be a more organized and practical way of achieving this.
const CategoryRequiredFieldSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  category_id: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Category",
    require: true,
  },
  required_field_name: { type: String, require: true },
  required_field_value: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, require: true },
});



Use dynamic validation based on category:
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ListingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  type: { type: String, required: true },
  bathrooms: { type: Number },
  locks: { type: Boolean },
});

ListingSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  if (this.type === 'entire place') {
    if (this.bathrooms == null) {
      return next(new Error('Bathrooms are required for entire place'));
    }
  } else if (this.type === 'private room') {
    if (this.locks == null) {
      return next(new Error('Locks are required for private room'));
    }
  }
  next();
});

const Listing = mongoose.model('Listing', ListingSchema);

Create categories and their rules in code. Adjust validation logic without new models.
